# Почему экранируются html теги в django шаблоне?

Tags: python, django

Я пишу в свой блог статью в админ-панели django.

Указываю, например:

```
<p>Параграф</p>
```

Сохраняю пост, и статья отображается с этими тегами.

Как сделать так, чтобы html-теги выполняли своё прямое назначение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением в шаблон (в моём случае "base.html")

```
{% autoescape off %}
....................
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! В жизни бы не догадался.
Здоровья Вам!

Answer (score 5):

Для создания текста с разметкой можно воспользоваться различными django батарейками, к примеру, django-tinymce.

Устанавливаете

```
 $ pip install django-tinymce
```

Добавляете в список установленных приложений

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'tinymce',
)
```

Добавляете пути в urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

В модели вместо TextField используете HTMLField

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    content = HTMLField()
```

Помимо этого:
[Список различных WYSIWYG редакторов](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/)

Comment: Совет хороший, только вот не совсем ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Для этого вы можете воспользоваться шаблонным фильтром `safe`

```
{% for item in articles %}
    {{ item|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Подробнее https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

**p.s** Вы должны доверять источнику ваших данных (например заполняете через админку и только вы), в случае если это сможет вводить пользователь, то он сможет использовать тег `<script>` и делать всё что душе угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы их пишете в поле `TextField` модели, скорее всего, очевидно, что они воспринимаются как текст.
Если хотите выводить все статьи в `<p>`, просто используйте параграф в темплейт тегах.
Пример кода:

```
{% for item in articles %}
    <p> {{ item }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Да, Вы абсолютно правы, у меня в модели имено "TexField" указан.

Comment: @Borsh предложил отличное решение, я не знал об этой батарейке

Comment: Ага! я сейчас пробую прикрутить это всё.)

Answer (score 1):

Использование

```
{% autoescape off %}
....................
{% endautoescape %}
```

очень опасно, к примеру если я вместо текста введу скрипт

```
<script>console.log("Дыра в безопасности сайта")</script>
```

то скрипт выполнится